# Cannot swap eth for exact tokens: TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, tokens, uniswap

I can't swap eth for exact tokens because of the error...

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert -- Reason given: TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED.
```

The code, I write with the help of documentation of V2_router...

```
function swapEthForExactTokensTest(
        uint256 _amountOut,
        address _tokenOut,
        address _to
    ) external payable {
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = WETH;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;

        IUniswapV2Router01(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS).swapETHForExactTokens{value: msg.value}
        (_amountOut, path, _to, block.timestamp);

        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success, "refund failed");
    }
```

now, I'm testing it...

```
const AMOUNT_OUT_MIN = 2;
const DAI = "0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f";
const TOKEN_OUT = DAI;

it('should swap eth for exact token', async()=>{

        tokenOut = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_OUT);
        testUniswap = await TestUniswap.new();

        await testUniswap.swapEthForExactTokensTest(

            AMOUNT_OUT_MIN,
            tokenOut.address,
            TO,

            {
                from: WHALE,
                value: "10"
            }

        );

        console.log(`out ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);

    })
```

I'm getting the error that is mentioned above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `await testUniswap.swapEthForTokens(AMOUNT_OUT_MIN,tokenOut.address,TO,{from:wethDaiWhale,value: Value});`
where,
`Value =  web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');`.